# Access External Objects From jQuery CallBack Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Scenario:

```
My_Object = {

  my_div: "#mydiv",

  my_method: function()
  {
    $(this.my_div).fadeOut("slow", function() { $(this.my_div).fadeIn("slow"); });
  }

}
```

'this.my_div' is not being recognized in the fadeIn call, as 'this' doesn't point to the original object anymore. How to I pass the original object to the callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store "this" in temporary variable:

```
My_Object = {

  my_div: "#mydiv",

  my_method: function()
  {
    var tmp = this;
    $(this.my_div).fadeOut("slow", function() { $(tmp.my_div).fadeIn("slow"); });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because inside the fadeOut() callback, `this` is now the element being faded out. I assume you want to fade it back in so just do this:

```
My_Object = {
  my_div: "#mydiv",
  my_method: function() {
    $(this.my_div).fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).fadeIn("slow"); // refers to the same object being faded out
    });
  }
}
```

The Javascript `this` concept is a little confusing.

Comment: I accepted your answer for this scenario, however in other case I would just do `var _this = this` and use `_this` in the callback function. Oh brother, 3 years ago I had no idea what I was doing :D