# JQuery - access external object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable object with 2 methods. One of them (`createdRow`) contains a callback which calls the other one (`getFieldType`).

```
jsTable = $('#ResolvedTable').DataTable( {

   //some other components

    getFieldType: function (id) {
      //some code
    },

    createdRow: function (row, data,index) {

            var table = $('#ResolvedTable').DataTable();
            var datatext = table.$('input, text');
            var self = this;

                //for each input text in the table perform the events
              $(datatext).each(function() {
                    var field;

                    //listen for the enter key
                    $(this).keydown(function (e) {
                        field = self.getFieldType($(this).attr('id'));   
                        handleInputKeyDown(e.keyCode,$(this).val(), field, $(this));
                    });
         });
    }

)}
```

On a `keydown` event, I want to call `getFieldType` from `createdRow`.
I am trying to reference the DataTable object using `self`, but the reference fails:

> Uncaught TypeError: self.getFieldType is not a function

Therefore, how can I call `getFieldType`?

My question is not a duplicate of
[Access External Objects From jQuery CallBack Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809290/access-external-objects-from-jquery-callback-functions) because in my case, control goes into the `keydown` callback, without touching the rest of the code.

Comment: Can you do it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/zyz8sjkz/

Comment: Either way it would never work. What you try is to access a property on dataTables settings - the correct notation should be `self.fnSettings().getFieldType()` but the settings object will only hold default values including those there is matchable from the passed options, `getFieldType` is ignored, never copied. Why not just have `getFieldType` as local function inside `createdRow`?

Comment: Because I want to avoid code duplication. I am calling it a second time in some other code which I haven't posted here.